# default.png for different target(lite and full version)

Tags: ios

I hope to set different default.png for lite version and full version.
But it looks like I can only set one default.png.
Is there any easy solution to switch default.png for lite and full version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy different resources over in Xcode for different build targets. Just add the new Default.png's into the project, and then edit the Build Phases rule for Copying Resources (click on the xcodeproj to bring it up).